# I am having a problems with my Spring Boot application not starting up

Tags: java

I have trying to get into full stack development and this is a starter project. I think this is something to do with my @beans perhaps one of my classes not being found.

Ive tried changing my dependencies in my pom and have tried naming my beans but neither worked for me.

This is the error that i am getting:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-27T21:34:20.993+01:00 ERROR 71951 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationController' defined in file [/Users/main/Documents/ecommerceBackend/target/classes/com/nea/ecommerceBackend/api/controller/auth/AuthenticationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/Users/main/Documents/ecommerceBackend/target/classes/com/nea/ecommerceBackend/service/UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
at com.nea.ecommerceBackend.EcommerceBackendApplication.main(EcommerceBackendApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/Users/main/Documents/ecommerceBackend/target/classes/com/nea/ecommerceBackend/service/UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'encryptionService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:498) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'encryption.salt.rounds' in value "${encryption.salt.rounds}"
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:200) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:918) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:764) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:492) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
... 50 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0

```
Here is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.nea</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerceBackend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerceBackend</name>
    <description>Nea E-commerce website. </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my AuthenticationController class:

```
package com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.controller.auth;

import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.model.LoginBody;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.model.LoginResponse;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.model.RegistrationBody;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.exception.UserAlreadyExistException;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.service.UserService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;


import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;




//@RestController
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auth")


public class AuthenticationController {


    private UserService userService;

    public AuthenticationController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody RegistrationBody registrationBody){
        try {
            userService.registerUser(registrationBody);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
        } catch (UserAlreadyExistException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).build();
        }


    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> loginUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginBody loginBody){
        String jwt = userService.loginUser(loginBody);
        if(jwt == null){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        } else {
            LoginResponse response = new LoginResponse();
            response.setJwt(jwt);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        }
    }

}
```

Here the EncryptionService class:

```
package com.nea.ecommerceBackend.service;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class EncryptionService {

    @Value("${encryption.salt.rounds}")
    public int saltRounds;
    private String salt;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        salt = BCrypt.gensalt(saltRounds);
    }

    public String encryptPassword(String password){
        return BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt);
    }

    public boolean verifyPassword(String password, String hash){
        return BCrypt.checkpw(password, hash);
    }

}
```

Here is the UserService Class:

```
package com.nea.ecommerceBackend.service;

import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.model.LoginBody;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.model.RegistrationBody;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.exception.UserAlreadyExistException;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.model.LocalUser;
import com.nea.ecommerceBackend.model.dao.LocalUserDAO;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserService {


    private LocalUserDAO localUserDAO;
    private EncryptionService encryptionService;

    private JWTService jwtService;

    public UserService(LocalUserDAO localUserDAO, EncryptionService encryptionService, JWTService jwtService) {
        this.localUserDAO = localUserDAO;
        this.encryptionService = encryptionService;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
    }




    public LocalUser registerUser(RegistrationBody registrationBody) throws UserAlreadyExistException {
        if(localUserDAO.findByEmailIgnoreCase(registrationBody.getEmail()).isPresent()
                || localUserDAO.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(registrationBody.getUsername()).isPresent()){
            throw new UserAlreadyExistException();
        }

        LocalUser user = new LocalUser();
        user.setEmail(registrationBody.getEmail());
        user.setFirstname(registrationBody.getFirstName());
        user.setLastname((registrationBody.getLastName()));
        user.setUsername(registrationBody.getUsername());

        user.setPassword(encryptionService.encryptPassword(registrationBody.getPassword()));
        return localUserDAO.save(user);

    }

    public String loginUser(LoginBody loginBody) {
        Optional<LocalUser> opUser = localUserDAO.findByUsernameIgnoreCase(loginBody.getUsername());
        if (opUser.isPresent()) {
            LocalUser user = opUser.get();
            if (encryptionService.verifyPassword(loginBody.getPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
                return jwtService.generateJWT(user);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the WebSecurityConfig Class:

```
package com.nea.ecommerceBackend.api.security;




import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;




@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean(name = "security")
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have more things to add?

Comment: What kind of things should i add? @MaythamFahmi

Comment: it's hard to tell from what you've posted, but I think I'd be checking the ComponentScan of the main class that starts your application

Comment: Is there anything else than i can send or tell you for some more details. Also should there be anything i should be checking in particular in those areas? @DaveH

Answer (score 1):

it says "Could not resolve placeholder '**encryption.salt.rounds**' in value "${encryption.salt.rounds}". Did you define this in your application.properties file? Is there any typo?

Comment: I did define it but there was a typo. I forgot an s at the end of rounds. Thank you very much @Murat

Comment: I am happy that you found the solution. Thanks :)